# Python: How to compare a unicode with unicode within variable

Tags: python, unicode, comparison

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem, thanks all for your time.

First of all, these are the requirements:

1. The comparison **MUST** be within variables. (Compare 2 variables contain unicode)
2. The version of Python **MUST** be 2.x , I know version 3 has solved this problem, but unfortunately it won't work with me.

So hello, I have a bot coded with python, and I would like to make it compare 2 non-English letters (unicode).

The problem I have is, the letters MUST be within variables, so I can't use:

> u'letter'

Both letters I would like to compare **MUST** be within variables.

I have tried:

> letter1 == letter2

it's showing this error:
    E:\bots\KiDo\KiDo.py:23: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  import sys

and always returns False even the 2 letters are the same.
**So I guess it means I'm comparing 2 unicode letters.**

And tried:

> letter = unicode(letter)

but it shows this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have searched all over Google, but all I could find is using u' ', but this won't work with the variables.

Thank you.

Comparison Code:

```
word1 = parameters.split()[0]
word2 = parameters.split()[1]
word3 = parameters.split()[2]
word4 = parameters.split()[3]
word5 = parameters.split()[4]
if word1[0] == letter:
    if word2[0] == letter:
        if word3[0] == letter:
            if word4[0] == letter:
                if word5[0] == letter:
                    reply(type, source,u'True')
```

Comment: i am not sure I totally follow but maybe this lib can help https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: are you sure when use `letter1 == letter2` it show false always ? are them really same?

Comment: What is the encoding that is used?

Comment: Looks like you may not actually have unicode strings on both sides.  Use print(type(letter1)) or whatever for more info.  Remember that UTF-8 from the great outside world has to be decoded - text.decode('utf-8'), before it'll be unicode.  Additionally, code you paste around between terminals and editors can be in rather unpredictable encodings, so lean heavily on the type() to check.  Lastly, your output will need to be put back into UTF8, say print(text.encode('utf-8')) to output it.  Try to avoid having UTF-8 text loose in your python2 program, it causes grief.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm sorry but this lib is the same as all other solutions, it doesn't deal with variables, what I want is to make a list, choose one item randomly, put it in a variable, then compare it to a unicode.

Comment: @Kasra Yes, I'm 100% sure they are the same, because I made the bot print both letters & they are the same, but it still shows an error with the comparison.

Comment: whats your python version ?

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys I'm dealing with Arabic letters, as far as I know they're considered unicode, and I'm not having a problem with the output, the output is showing Arabic letters with no loss or rubbish, the only problem is the comparison.

Comment: @Kasra 2.7 it's the best version of 2.x to work with me, I've tried all the others.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I beg your pardon?

Comment: how you compare ? pls add your try code to question !

Comment: @Kasra this is the comparison code, and I can post the whole code if you want to.

Comment: so which variables you have been compared in this code ? whats `reply` function ?

Comment: whats parameters ? and how you know  word1[0] == letter is a unicode comparison ? if its your mean ?

Comment: @Kasra the letter, is a randomly chosen letter from a list, while word1,2,3,4,5 are words entered by the user, so the comparison will be between the contents of the variable letter, and the first letter of user's input.

reply function is just like the print function, if the result of this comparison is Ture, then the bot will send me a message saying True, or else, it will continue to the rest of the code.

Comment: @Kasra parameters is the command that the user sends to bot.

i.e: command parm1 parm2 parm3 parm4 parm5.

so, word1 = parameters.split()[0] , will assign parm1 to word1.

and I'm sure word1[0] == letter is a unicode comparison, because I made the bot send me the contents of word1[0] & letter, and they're the same, but it still shows an error with the comparison.

Comment: in this case you have 5 nested for loop that if one of them be false the code dont be continue ! i havnt any idea ! just i post an answer to see whats the out put of my code ! like this !

Answer (score 3):

Look, the letter ç (a char that is not presented in ASCII) may be represented as a str object or as an unicode object (maybe you are a little confused about what unicode means).

Also, if you are trying to create an unicode object that is not present in ASCII table, you must pass another encoding table:

```
unicode('ç')
```

This will raise an UnicodeDecodeError because 'ç' is not in ASCII, but

```
unicode('ç', encoding='utf-8')
```

will work, because 'ç' is presented in UTF-8 encoding table (as your Arabic letters may be).

You can compare unicode objects with unicode objects as the same way you can compare str objects with str objects, and all this must work fine.

Also, you can compare a str object with unicode object but this is error prone if you are comparing not ASCII characters: 'ç' as a str is '\xc3\xa7' but as unicode it is just '\xe7' (returning False in a comparison).

So @Karsa may be really right. The problem is with your 'variables' (in Python, a better word is objects). You must certify that you are comparing just str or just unicode objects.

So, a better code could be:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def compare_first_letter(phrase, compare_letter):
    # making all unicode objects, with utf-8 codec
    compare_letter = unicode(compare_letter,encoding='utf-8')
    phrase = unicode(phrase,encoding='utf-8')
    # taking the first letters of each word in phrase
    first_letters = [word[0] for word in phrase.split()]
    # comparing the  first letters with the letter you want
    for letter in first_letters:
        if letter != compare_letter:
            return False
    return True # or your reply function

letter = 'ç'
phrase_1 = "one two three four"
phrase_2 = "çarinha çapoca çamuca"

print(compare_first_letter(phrase_1,letter))
print(compare_first_letter(phrase_2,letter))
```

Comment: Although I'm more sure that is a unicode more that str object, but I've edited the code and did like what you did,  

    letter = unicode(letter, encoding='utf-8')
    word1 = parameters.split()[0]
    word2 = parameters.split()[1]
    word1 = unicode(word1, encoding='utf-8')
    word2 = unicode(word1, encoding='utf-8')  
now the execution shows this error:  
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

this is my try base on any thing you say :

```
>>> b=u'letter'
>>> a=u'letter'
>>> a==b
True
>>> a=u'letter2'
>>> a==b
False
```

so im sure that there is a problem with your variables ! i suggest before you compare them try to print them ! to see whats under the variables !

Comment: I did print all the variables, and they are all the same, so basically, it **MUST** return True, but there must be something wrong with the comparison, that's why it's returning False.

Comment: If you print Unicode to a console, Python automatically encodes the Unicode to the console's encoding.  So if you have a UTF-8 terminal.  Printing Unicode and printing a UTF-8 encoded character will look the same, but they won't compare the same unless you convert them both to the same format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand Unicode vs. an encoding.

Refer to this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Note the following...  UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, but is not Unicode.  The `# coding: utf-8` declaration at the top of the source below declares the encoding of the source file **as saved on disk**.  `a = u'ç'` declares a *Unicode* variable.  `b = 'ç'` is a *byte string* in the source encoding (utf-8).

Note that `repr` displays different source-like representation of the string so you can tell the difference.  `type` indicates the object type.

```
# coding: utf-8
a = u'ç'
b = 'ç'

print a
print b
print repr(a)
print repr(b)
print type(a)
print type(b)
print a==b                  # Not comparing same types.
print a==b.decode('utf8')   # Comparing both as Unicode strings.
print a.encode('utf8')==b   # Comparing both as byte strings.
```

`a` and `b` print the same, but are *not* the same:

```
ç
ç
u'\xe7'
'\xc3\xa7'
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'str'>
C:\Users\metolone\Desktop\Script1.py:11: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  print a==b
False
True
True
```

Your `letter1` and `letter2` are two different types of strings.

Here's a complete example reading a word list from a file and taking input from a user:

```
import sys
import codecs

# The word list was saved in UTF-8 encoding.  It can be in any encoding
# as long as the correct one is specified when reading it in.
# `codecs.open` will convert the input to Unicode.
with codecs.open('words.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    word_list = f.read().strip().splitlines()

print 'word_list and type:',word_list,type(word_list[0])

# Different consoles can have different input encodings.  Let's see what it is.
print 'My terminal encoding:',sys.stdin.encoding

# Read a word in the input encoding.  We'll convert to Unicode later.
word = raw_input('Word? ')
print 'word, content and type:',word,repr(word),type(word)

# Now decode the input to Unicode.
word = word.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
print 'converted word, content and type:',word,repr(word),type(word)

# Compare the two Unicode strings
print 'Comparison:',word in word_list
```

Output from US Windows console.  Note that different consoles have different encodings.  Linux is usually UTF-8.  Non-US Windows console's can be different.

```
word_list and type: [u'\ufeffadi\xf3s', u'ping\xfcino'] <type 'unicode'>
My terminal encoding: cp437
Word? pingüino
word, content and type: pingüino 'ping\x81ino' <type 'str'>
converted word, content and type: pingüino u'ping\xfcino' <type 'unicode'>
Comparison: True
```

Comment: Let's take it simply, how the non-English letters (Like Arabic) are represented in the computer, Encoding means: convert (information or an instruction) into a particular form. while Unicode: an international encoding standard for use with different languages and scripts, by which each letter, digit, or symbol is assigned a unique numeric value that applies across different platforms and programs. so, when I'm trying to compare 2 Arabic letters, doesn't that mean I'm trying to compare 2 unicode letters?

Comment: No, as my example illustrates. `a` and `b` are not stored the same way.  `a` is stored as a Unicode string object, while `b` is stored as an encoded byte string.  As the warning indicates, it is trying to convert `b` to Unicode to make the comparison and failing.  It fails because Python 2.X defaults to decoding using ASCII and the data is in UTF-8 encoding.  Comparing `a == b.decode('utf-8')` would fix the issue.  Even Unicode strings have to be encoded internally in some format.  On Python 2.X, that happens to actually be UTF-16.  You have to compare the same encodings.

Comment: Consider `a == b` above as `u'\xe7' == '\xc3\xa7'`. Obviously not equal, right?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, but the problem is, I think you didn't read the first requirement I asked for, **"The comparison MUST be within variables."** because letter1 must be randomly chosen from a list, while letter2, is the _input_ of the user, so basically, I can't use u'letter2', and I have tried `letter2 = unicode(letter2)` but it didn't work as well. I'm sorry, but seems like you're concentrating on what I said, but not the solution.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: `a` and `b` **are** variables.  You need to convert your variables to the same type. `a` and `b` are two different types.  It doesn't matter how you get the values in the variables.  You *must* compare the same variable types.  `.encode(encoding)` turns Unicode strings into byte strings, and `.decode(encoding)` turns byte strings into Unicode strings.  I'll add an example of the conversion.

Comment: Basically, after reading the user's input, convert it into a Unicode string using `.decode(encoding)` before comparing it to your Unicode character lists.  It would help if you had a **complete** example of your program to tell you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you didn't read the edit, I've already solved it since 15 Sept. using the encode(encoding), but still, thanks for you time.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to compare single letters you could always compare the actual value using `ord(a)==ord(b)`.

In answer to the example posted:

```
>>> def check(b):
...    a = u'ي'
...    return (b==a, ord(a), ord(b), ord(a)==ord(b))
... 
>>> check(u'ي')
(True, 1610, 1610, True)
>>>
```

*You do need to be consistent in marking unicode as unicode, i.e. putting the* `u` *before the quotes.*

Comment: In fact I am trying to compare single letters.
but it's showing this error:
> TypeError: ord() Expected a character, but string of length 2 found.

Comment: @KiDo maybe this is happening because you are comparing str objects and not unicode objects.

Comment: @PabloPalácios I'm comparing 2 Arabic letters, and as far as I know, they're considered as unicode.

Comment: -1: Didn't work. I tried to compare `ord(c) == ord(u'”')` and it returned `False` when `c` was `u'”'`.

Comment: `Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c=u'"'
>>> ord(c)
34
>>> ord(u'"')
34
>>> ord(u'"') == ord(c)
True
>>> 
`

Comment: @SteveBarnes I'm sorry, but it doesn't work with Arabic letters.

Comment: @KiDo - Could you give an example?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Sure, but know that it won't work on the terminal of Python, because Python will convert all Arabic letters to a question mark. So, I've made the comparison as the way you gave me into .py file, but the bot still returns False.
Here is the code:

Comment: @SteveBarnes `def handler_check(type, source, parameters):
        a = 'ي'
        if a == parameters:
                reply(type, source, u'True')
        else:
                reply(type, source, u'False')`  
**the input was: ي* and still the result False, _[11:07:04] | KiDo: check ي
[11:07:04] | Avril Lavigne2: False_

Comment: @SteveBarnes same as all the answers before, I can't use `u` before the quotes, you are triggering the function from the command line (where you can input the letters manually), but if you read the first line in my question, when the user enters a letter, it will be saved into a variable then the bot proceed with the comparison, in this case, it's not possible to use the `u` with a variable.